# How to recognise a deleted account from the GuldenD response

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

When deleting an account using the deleteaccount command a "true" result is returned. After that, when querying the accounts using the listaccounts command the account is listed with [Deleted] appended to its name field. However this is indistinguishable from an account with a name that actually ends with "[Deleted]". Is there any other way to only list only the really active accounts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is currently no way to obtain this information via RPC, however the wallet does store this information internally, so it is available to internal code. i.e. Simply adding [Deleted] to the name will not make the wallet treat the account as deleted.
https://github.com/Gulden/gulden-official/blob/master/src/account.h#L39

The listaccounts RPC command should definitely be extended to make this information accessible.

Comment: So how does the QT GUI handle this? Does it have access to the internal state somehow?

Comment: Qt GUI has access to the 'type' (which you can consider a state) as per link above as this is exposed to the c++ library. The 'type' just isn't currently exposed to RPC in any way, this is more an oversight in the RPC (nobody thought to expose it to RPC yet) than anything else (not an intentional design decision).